# Rails 3 & select_tag - how to load data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, select

I stored my menu structure in DB table as:

```
id | item | par
1  | A    | 0
2  | B    | 0
3  | C    | 1
4  | D    | 1
```

I think abou the way, how to get to my SELECT options the statement as:

```
A
B
A -> C
A -> D
```

I am able to make the statement as:

```
A
B
C
D
```

with using the following command:

> <%= select("menu_item", "menu_id", Menu.all.collect {|p| [ p.item,
>   p.id ] }, {:include_blank => ''}) %>

But I can't find a way, how to achieve the statement as in the middle example... I would like to ask you - could anyone help me, please, with this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you implementing your own single table inheritance? If so, I'd suggest to take a look at https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry. Then you can use all it's fancy helper methods to get all the children for each menu item that has any.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want a helper which creates the desired label.  So if you named your helper `full_item_name`, you'd have

```
<%= select("menu_item", "menu_id", Menu.all.collect {|p| [ full_item_name(p.item), p.id ] }, {:include_blank => ''}) %>
```

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean, but right now I am struggling with a way, how to get the data (how to make a the full_item_name helper)

Comment: My model looks like that in the first post - of course I have in my DB table more columns, but those are not important

Comment: I understand, but could you just post the code for your model?  That way we can write some code to show you how to do the association.